# What is happening during the String.init

Tags: swift, string, initialization

I found this example function that takes a integer and then sorts the number from largest to smallest. Example input: 12345 output: 54321. The solution works but I am trying to understand the String.init part. Could anyone explain what is going on?

```
func descendingOrder(of number: Int) -> Int {
    let s =  String(number).sorted().reversed()
    return Int(s.compactMap(String.init).joined())!
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`s` is of type `ReversedCollection<[String.Element]>` so it makes the conversion from `String.Element` to `String` this is the meaning of `String.init` inside loop of `compactMap`

When you see `DataType.init` you need to know that the item being looped is a paramter for the init of that type so loop occurs over the characters of the String s to make a new [String] as a result

Developer complicates the line , it could be simplified to this for netter understanding

```
func descendingOrder(of number: Int) -> Int {
    let s =  String(number).sorted().reversed() // sort and reverse the string descendinng 
    let arr = s.compactMap(String.init) // convert characters to array of strings
    let joined = arr.joined() // join them in 1 string
    let res = Int(joined)! // convert string to int
    return res
}
```

OR as in comments

```
func descendingOrder(of number: Int) -> Int {
    let s =  String(number).sorted().reversed() // sort and reverse the string descendinng
    let arr = s.map{ String($0) } // convert characters to array of strings
    let joined = arr.joined() // join them in 1 string
    let res = Int(joined)! // convert string to int
    return res
}
```

Comment: add this example for better explanation : Int(s.compactMap({String($0)}).joined())!

Comment: I think the element inside `compactMap` is `Character` so `String.init` with call `String.init(_ c: Character)` automatically